# Get value of multidimensional array by other value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've got a multidimensional PHP array in that form:

```
array(
  (int) 0 => array(
    'Category' => array(
      'id' => '01',
      'title' => 'SomeCategory'
    )
  ),
  (int) 1 => array(
    'Category' => array(
      'id' => '02',
      'title' => 'OtherCategory'
    )
  )
)
```

I want to get the title of the category with a specific id, e.g. SomeCategory when I have the id 01.

Is there a better (more performant or easier) way to do it than this one?

```
foreach($categories as $nestedCategory) {
  foreach($nestedCategory as $category) {
    if($category['id'] === $postedData['Submission.Category.0.id']) {
      debug($category['title']);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the id's are unique you could rewrite the array

```
foreach( $array as $n => $item ) {
    $arr[$item['Category']['id']] = $item;
}

// get id 02
echo $arr['02']['Category']['title']; // output: OtherCategory
```